# Extracting CGColor out of UIColor

Tags: ios, uicolor, cgcolor

I have a UIColor initiated with [UIColor colorWithRed:Green:Blue:Alpha] and I want to extract its corresponding CGColor to use with CGContextSetFillColorWithColor.

I tried [[UIColor colorWithRed...] CGColor] but for some reason I get no coloring.
I

```
[[UIColor colorWithRed:216 green:156 blue:1 alpha:1] CGColor]
```

The weird thing is that when I use:

```
[[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor]
```

It works just fine.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The actual code:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:216 green:156 blue:1 alpha:1].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

I don't think its code-related - again, if I change the UIColor to a constant color it all works.

The purpose of the code is to create an UIImage filled with a specific color.

Comment: `[UIColor colorWithRed:216 green:156 blue:1 alpha:1]` is white. You need `[UIColor colorWithRed:216/255.0 green:156/255.0 blue:1/255.0 alpha:1]`

Comment: I don't think you're correct, and even if so - It doesn't fix the problem :(

Comment: Yes, I'm right. You need to supply values in the range 0.0 - 1.0 for each color component. Another option is to do `[[UIColor colorWithRed:216/255.0 green:156/255.0 blue:1/255.0 alpha:1] set];`.

Comment: @rmaddy is correct about dividing the hex values by 255.0f.

Comment: You are in fact right, I feel silly. solved it. thanks :)